# Error while accessing remote MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, connectivity, centos

Trying to access remote MongoDB. Got the following error:

```
C:\Users\ranjj_000>mongo <SERVER_IP_HERE>:28017

MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: 111.93.128.60:28017/test
2014-04-22T12:19:45.084+0530 Socket recv() errno:10054 An existing connection was     forcibly closed by the remote host. 111.93.128.60:28017
2014-04-22T12:19:45.087+0530 SocketException: remote: <SERVER_IP_HERE>:28017 error: 9001 socket exception [RECV_ERROR] server [<SERVER_IP_HERE>:28017]
2014-04-22T12:19:45.088+0530 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2014-04-22T12:19:45.093+0530 Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 111.93.128.60:28017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
```

exception: connect failed

Server is: CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port 28017 is usually the [HTTP Console interface](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-console), not the port you should be using to connect via the shell.  Change the port to 27017 instead and retry.